# bash resource doesn't seem to be loading my .bashrc file

Tags: bash, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am having some trouble trying to load my `.bashrc` file through the `bash` Chef resource. My `.bashrc` is located in `/sh/.bashrc` This is my resource code:

```
bash "Source .bashrc" do
    cwd "/home/ameya"
    user "ameya"
    code "source /sh/.bashrc"
    action :run
end
```

My `.bashrc` has only the following bit:

```
export ME=ameya
```

So when I type `echo $ME` at the terminal I expect to see it print out `ameya` but nothing gets printed out. What is wrong with the way I have set things up? Thanks in advance

Comment: What does a shell started by Chef sourcing your file have to do with your own interactive shell sourcing a file at startup? Environment variables are process-local -- as soon as the shell where the `source` command happens exits, that command no longer has any effect (except on any child processes started and left behind).

Comment: I wanted to basically set ENV variables for the user and a lot of the examples that I saw showed that you can set environment variable either through the `environment` attribute in the `bash` resource or by sourcing a file which is what I am trying to do since passing in the values to the `environment` attribute is cumbersome

Comment: The `environment` attribute in the `bash` resource doesn't change environment variables long-term, or in a way which will apply to later interactive shells -- it only sets them for the individual invocation you're telling Chef to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.bashrc` for the user `ameya` is `/home/ameya/.bashrc`. If you want it to run a shared file, you might do the following:

```
file "/home/ameya/.bashrc" do
  content "source /home/sh/.bashrc"
done
```

When Chef runs `/home/sh/.bashrc`, the effect only lasts as long as that single shell instance, started by Chef, is running. If you want the effects of a `.bashrc` file to take effect on every interactive shell invocation, you need to arrange for it to be source'd during that startup process.

Comment: so would I be able to do that for the long term by sourcing the file in my .bash_profile?

Comment: `.bash_profile` is run once per login shell, `.bashrc` is run once per interactive shell. Really, you should be setting environment variables in `.bash_profile` only and not bothering with `.bashrc` for them at all -- `.bashrc` is the right place for settings that don't propagate to child processes.